# How to translate this line into 3d (godot)

Tags: godot

This line of code works in a previous program but I cannot figure out how to translate it to 3D, (I've tried adding tangent). How can I do this?

```
move_and_slide(Vector2(cos(rotation), sin(rotation)) * 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `KinematicBody` instead of (probably what you are using right now) `KinematicBody2D`. Then in argument to this function, you have to pass `Vector3`

Comment: All my nodes are relevant, the code was used in a previous program that was 2d and I want to use it function in a 3d game